# Angular Concat Multiple HTTP Requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like to use concat in order to subscribe to all HTTP requests that I have in an array. The array could have 1 or multiple http requests in it. I am currently creating my observable array like this:

```
requestArray.push(this.updateUser());
requestArray.push(this.updateCustomer());
```

And then I would like the requests to be submitted one at a time so I tried using concat like this:

```
concat(requestArray).subscribe(results => {
   console.log(results);
})
```

I would assume the results would be an array of the completed requests but instead it just prints out this:

```
Observable{_isScaler: false, source: Observable}
Observable{_isScaler: false, _subscribe: f}
```

It looks like its not actually subscribing to my observables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain JavaScript array is considered by `concat` (and basically any other operator that accepts an observable as its parameter) as so called `ObservableInput` where it just iterates its items and reemits every single one as a separate emissions.

So if you want `concat` to subscribe to items inside the array you'll have to destructurize it into parameterers:

```
concat(...requestArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the result to be an array after all your calls have completed, you can do so like this:

```
concat(...requestArray).pipe(
  toArray()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

This is basically the same thing:

```
merge(...requestArray, 1).pipe(
  toArray()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The difference with the second one is that you can explicitly decide how many concurrent requests you'd like. So if you want a few to run in parallel at a time without overwhelming the server, you can do so:

max 3 concurrent requests:

```
merge(...requestArray, 3).pipe(
  toArray()
).subscribe(console.log);
```